# Solutions for a functional equation

Tags: functions, inverse-function

What are the functions (complex or real) that accept these properties: $(f \circ f \circ f \circ f) (x) = x$ but $(f \circ f) (x) ≠ x$?
I mean that these functions are not self-inverse but their compositions with themselves are self-inverse.
I have not any clue for solving this functional equation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Further, you've written it wrong and ambiguously.  Presumably, you are curious about the real functions $f$ such that $(f\circ f\circ f\circ f\circ)(x)=x$ but $(f\circ f)(x)\neq x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that 
$f(f(f(f(x)))) = x$ for all $x$ but $f(f(x)) \ne x$ for at least some $x$.
The first equation implies that $f$ is one-to-one and onto.  It's not hard to show that there is no continuous solution.  On the other hand, it's not hard to find discontinuous solutions.  Just partition $\mathbb R$ into four sets $A, B, C, D$,
let $f$ be arbitrary one-to-one maps of $A$ onto $B$, $B$ onto $C$, $C$ onto $D$, and on $D$ let $f: x \mapsto y \in A$ where $f(f(f(y))) = x$.